# Next.js - Trying to call an api using an async func to get Image src

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, next.js

I am trying to learn react and next.js so I'm building a basic website for myself to try and learn some new skills, but I have run into a problem trying to return a url to use as an image src but im getting an error using export on the async func. Can someone help explain what I am doing wrong, thanks. Basically just calling DeepAI's img2txt api which should return a link to an image which is the src of my Image component. API docs: https://deepai.org/machine-learning-model/text2img

index:

```
 import Head from 'next/head';
    import Image from 'next/image';
    import React from "react";
    import TextTransition, { presets } from "react-text-transition";
    import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";
    
    const deepai = require('deepai');
    deepai.setApiKey('quickstart-QUdJIGlzIGNvbWluZy4uLi4K');
    const TEXTS = [
      "ok",
      "yes",
      "no"
    ];
    
  export async function getImage() {
      var resp = await deepai.callStandardApi("text2img", {
          text: "test",
      });
      return resp
  }

export default function Home() {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() =>
      setIndex(index => index + 1),
      3000 // every 3 seconds
    );
    return () => clearTimeout(intervalId);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>zack</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main>
        <div>
          <h1>
            welcome to my website
          </h1>
          <Image
            src = {resp}
            alt = "ai generated image"
            width = "500"
            height = "500"
          />
          <p>a collection of my <b><TextTransition
            text={TEXTS[index % TEXTS.length]}
            springConfig={presets.stiff}
            inline={true}
          /></b>
          </p>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

error:

```
ReferenceError: result is not defined
    at Home (C:\Users\zack\Desktop\website\personal-site\my-site\.next\server\pages\index.js:891:16)
    at processChild (C:\Users\zack\Desktop\website\personal-site\my-site\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3353:14)
    at resolve (C:\Users\zack\Desktop\website\personal-site\my-site\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3270:5)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (C:\Users\zack\Desktop\website\personal-site\my-site\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3753:22)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (C:\Users\zack\Desktop\website\personal-site\my-site\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3690:29)
    at renderToString (C:\Users\zack\Desktop\website\personal-site\my-site\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:4298:27)
    at Object.renderPage (C:\Users\zack\Desktop\website\personal-site\my-site\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:54:851)
    at Function.getInitialProps (C:\Users\zack\Desktop\website\personal-site\my-site\.next\server\pages\_document.js:293:19)
    at loadGetInitialProps (C:\Users\zack\Desktop\website\personal-site\my-site\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\utils.js:5:101)
    at renderToHTML (C:\Users\zack\Desktop\website\personal-site\my-site\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:54:1142)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async C:\Users\zack\Desktop\website\personal-site\my-site\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:107:97
    at async C:\Users\zack\Desktop\website\personal-site\my-site\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:100:142
    at async DevServer.renderToHTMLWithComponents (C:\Users\zack\Desktop\website\personal-site\my-site\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:132:387)
    at async DevServer.renderToHTML (C:\Users\zack\Desktop\website\personal-site\my-site\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\next-server.js:133:522)
```

Comment: Please show the complete error message and show the line referenced in the error.

Comment: did you just exposed some api key?

Comment: no i did not expose an api key this is a test key provided by deepai.

Comment: why you are defining and async function outside of Home

Comment: i am new how do i go about returning this string. having the async inside Home doesnt work either

Comment: Can you show the part of your code where `getImage()` is been used, and also where you have a variable `result` (which is triggering the error apparently)?